# How to call a function from unity library (C# function) in android when using unity as a library?

Tags: java, c#, android, android-studio, unity-game-engine

I am building an android application that shows 360-degree images in VRview. for this I am using unity as a library to show the 360 images (as a skybox). But I couldn't figure out a way to change the 360 images (skybox) based on the user input.

Here is what I did.

first I created a unity project imported a 360 image and made it skybox, wrote scripts, and prepared the VRview then exported it for android. Then I created an android studio project, imported and called the unity library from the android java class, and tested it on an actual device, and it worked fine. But it only works for only one 360-degree image.

To support multiple images, I created a function inside the C# script to change the image (skybox) of the scene and tried to call it from the android by passing a string that is used to identify which skybox to set.

This is explained in a question:

[How to call Unity C# method from Android java project by UnitySendMessage method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26404046/how-to-call-unity-c-sharp-method-from-android-java-project-by-unitysendmessage-m)

To call the C# function, It suggests using

> UnityPlayer. UnitySendMessage("Gameobject Name","Method","Message")

But it didn't work for me.

Here is the java class that is used to call the Unity library

```
public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
    public void toVr(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("data", "skybox1");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Here is the UnityPlayerActivity onCreate method from which I tried to call the Unity C# method

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String cmdLine = updateUnityCommandLineArguments(getIntent().getStringExtra("unity"));
    getIntent().putExtra("unity", cmdLine);


    mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this, this);
    setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
    mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String ss = i.getStringExtra("data");

    if (ss.equals("skybox1")) {
        UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Script", "initiateBackground", "skybox1");
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "no display", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Here is Unity C# code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SkyboxScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Material skyOne;
    public Material skytwo;

    void Start(){
    }

    public void initiateBackground(string skybox){
        if(skybox.Equals("skybox1")){
            RenderSettings.skybox = skytwo;
        }
    }

}
```

I need help to figure out how to call initiateBackground(string) method from the android java class. any type of help is appreciated.

Comment: it shound be mUnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("Script", "initiateBackground", "skybox1"); isn't it? Since you have defined like this "mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this, this);"